# How to retrieve a key value for a Firebase 3.0 item / Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Firebase 3.0 and coding and am having trouble retrieving a specific node ID and writing to it.  In the example below, I just created the user and now want to add that user to a specific facility.  How would I search for the facility named "Upper Paw" and then add the user to it

Current:

```
application  
    -facilities  
        -KRFGFn7TzKR8D0bMLW  
            facName: "Upper Paw"  
            facPhone: "5122223333"  
    -users  
        -MqrvHRBTRcPzrvAOdkklBzeFW7E2  
            firstName: "Ronnie"  
            lastName: "Last"
```

Goal:

```
application   
    -facilities  
        -KRFGFn7TzKR8D0bMLW  
            facName: "Upper Paw"  
            facPhone: "5122223333"
            users:   
                -MqrvHRBTRcPzrvAOdkklBzeFW7E2  
                    firstName: "Ronnie"  
                    lastName: "Last"  
    -users  

        -MqrvHRBTRcPzrvAOdkklBzeFW7E2  
            firstName: "Ronnie"  
            lastName: "Last"
```

Here is my code to pull up the values in facilities (which pulls up the all facility data, but unsure how to query and find the facility for Upper Paw and write additional data to it:

```
let facRef = rootRef.child("facilities")

            facRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

             print(snapshot.value)
```

Comment: The [codelab for iOS](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/) should give you some idea of how to get started. If you're having problems translating those learnings to your own project, show the code of what you've already tried. Otherwise we're just writing the code for you, which is not the most educational.

Comment: Thanks Frank! I was finally able to get the facility key with your help and then add the current user as a facEmployee under that facility.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let facRef = rootRef.child("facilities")

let faqQuery = facRef. queryOrderedByChild("facName"). queryEqualToValue("Upper Paw")

faqQuery.observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

    print(snapshot.value)
```

See the [Firebase documentation on querying](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) for more information.

For learning how to modify the data, see the [Firebase documentation on saving data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/save-data). Based on that your block could be:

```
 snapshot.ref.child("facMember").setValue("Ronnie L")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "DATABASE_URL")
    let usersRef = ref.child("users")
    usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "facName").queryEqual(toValue: "Upper Paw").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot)
   })
```